# UIcollectionView Reload ovelaps in ios 7

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, uicollectionview

I'm using UICollectionview in my app when i reload that it overlaps the subviews in uicollectionviewcell in ios 7 but in ios 6 it works fine, any one knows what could be the reason and how to solve this issues.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionViewCell *cell=[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            if ([self.collectionviewFlow.indexPathsForVisibleItems containsObject:indexPath]) {
                NSString *img_name=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_thumb%d.png",self.VaritiesName,(int)indexPath.row+1];
                imageVw=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed: img_name]];
                imageVw.frame=CGRectMake(10,10,100,100);
                [cell.contentView addSubview:imageVw];
            }
        });
    cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: post your some of code.

Comment: i have attached the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way... & **Let me know**

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionViewCell *cell=[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

      //  ********* Changed *******

       for (UIView *v in [cell.contentView subviews])
        [v removeFromSuperview];

     // ********** Changed **********
            if ([self.collectionviewFlow.indexPathsForVisibleItems containsObject:indexPath]) {
                NSString *img_name=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_thumb%d.png",self.VaritiesName,(int)indexPath.row+1];
                imageVw=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed: img_name]];
                imageVw.frame=CGRectMake(10,10,100,100);
                [cell.contentView addSubview:imageVw];
            }
        });
    cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Is this helpful to you?

Comment: i have one more doubt i use this code when i reload it takes huge memory and "Received memory warning." and crashes the app. pls help me...

Comment: Try to reduce the Image size if it is big or use ARC in your file/Project.

Comment: i have loading six images that is 3 rows with each row two images with size of 140*140 and i have ARC enabled project only..then also it crashes any idea for image size?

Comment: use Instrument tool & check where it needs more memory.

Comment: when i load imageview it consumes more memory and Received Memory Warning and crashes the app in ios 7 but in ios 6 it works fine.pls help here i'm struggle lots...

Comment: Are you load images in collectionview cell or anywhere else?

Comment: in CollectionView Cell only. what u have given in the above code.

Comment: try to release if imagevw after adding to cell as subview.

Comment: i'm using ARC it will automatically release it na... or we have release manually ?

Comment: @user1673099: Hi, I am also facing a same problem with 100 cells.I tried your solution but it is not working for me for iOS 8. Please tell me the solution to stop overlapping off cells issue.